How to integrate Clover sdk correctly on android POS
I want to create an android app for clover pos and just want to integrate clover sdk and perform some dummy transaction, can someone help how to do this?
new to clover sdk, have tried some steps but could get into it like merchant and clover developer

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
